# Highlighting files changed on a branch in Intellij IDEA Project section (similar to uncommitted changes)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

In IntelliJ IDEA is there a way to highlight the files changed on a current branch (i.e. all files changed in your previous commits) in the project section?

Obviously the git/history tab can be used to see the files but it is pretty cumbersome as it opens the diff instead of the actual file.

It's nice to just be able to quickly see the files you've been working with show up a different colour. I usually hold off on committing my changes until I'm nearly finished on something just so I can easily see the files I've been working with recently.

Answer (score 0):

See whether this works for you.
Open Git history, click one of the commit, then on the right page, right click and select "Edit Source", it will open all the files that were changed/updated/added on the Tab editor.

[image: Edit Source]

Answer (score 0):

> In IntelliJ IDEA is there a way to highlight the files changed on a current branch (i.e. all files changed in your previous commits) in the project section?

Currently, there is no option to set scope in Local Changes to a particular branch, please see and feel free to vote:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-161465